# Horizontally aligning HTML input fields correctly for Bootstrap 3 and responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a simple web page, using Bootstrap 3, where I am centering everything and then I have 2 input fields and a button. This I would like to get aligned in a nice looking manner and be responsive but for some reason I cannot get it working. Maybe I already know the problem - I don't understand the Bootstrap grid system good enough ;-)

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Do not use the first 4 columns as I want it centered -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

    <!-- Center the content in the middle 4 columns -->
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="form-group form-inline form-horizontal form-group-lg">
        <div>
          <!-- Input 1 -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Placeholder 1" />
          </div>
          <!-- Input 2 -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Placeholder 2" />
          </div>
          <!-- Submit button -->
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">Button 1 2 3</button>
        </div>

      </div> <!-- <div class="form-group form-inline form-horizontal form-group-lg"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div class="col-md-4"> -->

    <!-- Do not use the last 4 columns as I want it centered -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

  </div> <!-- <div class="row"> -->
</div> <!-- <div class="container"> -->
```

The above HTML code gives this result, which I do not want.
**I have this:**

[image: I have this]

Ideally I would like the 3 things (2 x input + button) to be gathered at the center of the screen with maybe 10 pixels betweem them.
**I want this:**

[image: I want this]

I have this JSFiddle demo, https://jsfiddle.net/33am99hj/

I have also tried excluding the `<div class="container">` and `<div class="row">` and then everything is at one line but then the input fields are overlapping and I cannot see them completely:

[image: Shadow going under the next input field]

Any ideas how I can get the content nicely centered with a little spacing between them and still be responsive (stacked when they cannot fit the screen)?

---

**SOLUTION** as mentioned by Marko Manojlovic:

I ended up with this JSFiddle solution, https://jsfiddle.net/ducbLsbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nicely formatted question,

What you first need to do is make one subgrid under yours  `<div class="col-md-4">`thats responsible for holding your form. With this new subgrid in place, you can then control the inputs width and responsive variations. With this in place, you can set the width and responsive widths to the sizes you need:

Sample code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Placeholder 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
       <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Placeholder 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Button 1 2 3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Class `form-control` on input field is responsible for matching the width of the input with your parent element (in sample case: `col-xs-12` and `col-sm-5`)

Classes `col-*-*` will also add the spacing between inputs you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have now updated the JSFiddle with this, https://jsfiddle.net/htpysa2r/, but is there any way to specify the space between the fields? I think there is a little too much space between them.

Comment: For spacing adjustment simple override `col-sm-4` padding-left, and padding-right. I would suggest adding some kind of class/id to the parent element so you avoid modified classes on a global level. For example `#my-custom-form .col-sm-4: padding-left: smaller space value; padding-right:smaller space value`;